# NSData getBytes(length)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I have a problem when using getBytes on an NSData object. This is the code:

```
if let blobBase64DecodedData = blob.base64DecodedData() {
    var URILength: UInt8 = 0
    if blobBase64DecodedData.count > 0 {

        let uriLengthRange: Range<Int> = 1..<3
        let testData =  (blobBase64DecodedData.subdata(in: uriLengthRange) as NSData)
        (blobBase64DecodedData.subdata(in: uriLengthRange) as NSData).getBytes(&URILength, length: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
        let uriDataRange: Range<Int> = 2..<(2+Int(URILength))
        let sURIData = blobBase64DecodedData.subdata(in: uriDataRange) <—CRASH HERE

        // further processing
    }
}
```

The problem is that the uriDataRange is bigger than what is in the blobBase64DecodedData object. So I believe there is a problem with the getBytes where URILenght is given a value. Does anyone know what the problem is? What exactly does that GetBytes do?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the format of the data, how is the length stored? It seems strange to me that uriLengthRange and uriDataRange *overlap,* and that you retrieve a single-byte value from a 2-byte range.

Comment: That is the problem... after investigation I found out the length of the data should be the second byte...Does Range<Int> = 1..<3 not extract one single byte? the second one?

Comment: `1..<3` is the range from 1 (including) to 3 (excluding), i.e. you are retrieving the bytes at offsets 1 and 2 from the data. Note that the first byte has offset zero, so this would be the second and third byte.

Comment: so range 2..<2 is only byte number 2

Comment: It would be easier if you *show* your data, and explain what values you expect.